# Ошибка при сборке maven проекта на стадии mvn deploy

Tags: java, spring, maven

При попытке вызвать `mvn deploy` получаю ошибку

```
Deployment failed: repository element was 
not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Проект пишу в IntelliJIDEA, JDK 12.0.1, maven 3.5.4

Мой pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <packaging>war</packaging>

   <groupId>habra</groupId>
   <artifactId>habr</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <version.jdk>1.6</version.jdk>
      <version.spring>4.0.2.RELEASE</version.spring>
      <version.spring.mongodb>1.4.0.RELEASE</version.spring.mongodb>
      <version.jackson>1.9.13</version.jackson>
      <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <!-- Все, что нужно для Spring -->

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>${version.spring}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
         <version>${version.spring}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>${version.spring}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
         <version>${version.spring}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
         <version>${version.spring.mongodb}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- MongoDB драйвер -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
         <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
         <version>2.11.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
         <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
         <version>${version.jackson}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Servlet Api -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
         <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.1</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>jstl</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Логгирование -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>log4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.5</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- TEST -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.11</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
         <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
         <version>1.3.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>jstl</groupId>
         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
         <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>


   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
               <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>

      </plugins>

   </build>


</project>
```

Пролазила большую часть стаковерфлоу, но ничего не помогло (или я что-то не так делаю), пробовала запустить через tomcat без стадии деплоя, но тоже ничего не вышло

Comment: Надо добавить `distributionManagement` секцию в `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример того что нужно добавить

```
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
      <id>nexus-site</id>
      <url>http://central_nexus/server</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Документация [тут](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#repository).